# Getting an element value when using autodividersSelector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have spent the last hours trying to figure out how to retrieve value within DOM. I am implementing a custom list divider using the JQuery function as shown in code below:

```
$('#postlist').listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
    var out = $(li)[0];
    console.log(out);
    return out;
   }
});
```

All I was getting so far was `[object HTMLLIElement]` on the divider heading

I have edited this bit to paste the final code that worked:

**Working Code**

```
$('#postlist').listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
       var out = li.find("p").map(function() {return $(this).text();});
       var out1 = out.get(1);
    return out1;
    }
});
```

**Output Image**

[image]

Comment: console.log(li) to see what this li is (json, jquery object, javascript object, array ...)

Comment: @mikakun I have added the requested console log result

Comment: cant see much, just copy paste

Comment: 'unable to get just the Date value ONLY' what do you mean ? what do you get ?

Comment: @mikakun all I am trying to achieve is group my posts with the divider by dates. So instead of the divider showing the post date, its displaying [object HTMLLIElement]

Comment: This is my test [site](http://howtodeployit.com/newdevotion/). When you inspect the elements, you will understand where I am coming from. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
$(li)[0]; //Dont wrap up with '$'. It's unecessary.
```

Use this:

```
li.find("p").eq(1).text();
```

Demo:http://jsfiddle.net/62LZm/

Comment: I have \already tried this, still not getting the needed value

Comment: what you want to retrieve?? `li` text content??

Comment: If you look at the link I provided in the main question, you will see what I am trying to achieve. Where the divider shows [object HTMLLIElement] I want it to simply show the date of post

Comment: OK I will get the fiddle when I get home. Even while I am not at home, I am still cracking my head on this issue. Thanks

Comment: great we are getting somewhere. That seems to work but just one thing. If you check the site now it displays the date for posts on the 5th but none for the 3rd. I will try and work on this. Thanks for your help so far. You are a star

Comment: `arrayofdates=li.find("p").map(function() {return $(this).text();});` / i don't think you need to reaccess the dom to get your li (`$("li")` is an overkill /your callback already provide li)

Comment: I simply thought using the autodividersSelector function would enable me group my posts by date. Didn't realize it was going to be this complex. If I just add **data-autodividers="true"** within my HTML div, it only adds the divider but using just first alphabet of each posts

Answer (score 0):

A BIG thanks also to @mikakun for the code he suggested. Using the .map function helped to better output the element I needed but I had to do some additional extra reading and coding to get the ultimate desired output. OK enough of my speech. This is my final code that worked perfectly after much brain cracking:

```
$('#postlist').listview({
    autodividers: true,
    autodividersSelector: function (li) {
       var out = li.find("p").map(function() {return $(this).text();});
       var out1 = out.get(1);
    return out1;
    }
});
```

Sorry I don't have enough reputation to past the image here but I have edited it in the original case and also added the result there.

I hope this also comes in handy for others.